# How to elegantly hardcode a given model for a simulation

Tags: ruby, simulation

I have the following code:

```
class Point
attr_reader :left, :right, :straigth, :next_point, :label
  def initialize(left,right,straigth,next_point,label)
    @straigth = straigth
    @right = right
    @left = left
    @next_point = next_point
    @label = label
  end
end
```

I'm trying to implement the following model using the above data structure using a more elegant solution than just creating a new variable for each point and then linking them together.  (e.g not like this)

```
a = Point.new(Point.new .... )
b = Point.new( ... , a, etc ...)
```

[image]

I first thought of having arrays within arrays such as 
[a,b,c,d,[e,f,g,h, ... ] and match A with E and F and then B with G and H however when we reach the third level points are shared. E has N but F also has N. Also M is connected to L and U.

What's the most elegant way to hardcode this into a variable for simulation purposes?

Comment: What simulation are you trying? Why would you need nested Points?

Comment: There are different types of points which inherit the constructor given but for simplicity i did not include that code. Since each point is different I need to travel from one point 1000 steps and see where it takes me ( because of different types of points there are a lot of possibilities)

Comment: So to clarify, you want a way to link different points? For example, A -> E -> N etc?